# C# - Отменить закрытие WebBrowser перехватом WM_DESTROY или WM_CLOSE

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

У меня есть форма с экземпляром WebBrowser на ней. В него загружается страница сайта, на которой есть ссылка вида '<a onClick="self.close();">Закрыть окно</a>'.
При нажатии ее выдает сообщение, что скрипты пытается закрыть WebBrowser. Если согласиться, то WebBrowser просто зависает.
Поэтому стоит задача перехватить и отменить это закрытие.

После гугления нашел следующее решение. Расширить класс WebBrowser, чтобы перегрузить метод 'WndProc()', чтобы он ловил событие WM_PARENTNOTIFY, в котором передается WM_DESTROY. Однако, решение было предназначено для организации корректного закрытия формы браузера. В моем же случае мне нужно отменить закрытие и перейти по конкретному URL. Мне удается перехватить WM_DESTROY, но WebBrowser все равно убивается и зависает. Код использованного решения ниже:

```
public class ExtendedWebBrowser : WebBrowser
  {
    // Define constants from winuser.h
    private const int WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x210;
    private const int WM_DESTROY = 2;

    public string BackUrl { get; set; };

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
      switch (m.Msg)
      {
        case WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
          if (!DesignMode)
          {
            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == WM_DESTROY)
            {
              Navigate(BackUrl);
            }
          }
          DefWndProc(ref m);
          break;
        default:
          base.WndProc(ref m);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Вопрос: Как предотвратить дальнейшую обработку WM_DESTROY или WM_CLOSE?

Comment: По идее, нужно убрать вызов DefWndProc.

Comment: @SmInc Не помогает. Подозреваю, что обрабатывать WM_DESTROY уже поздно, т.к. событие WM_CLOSE уже обработано и пытается закрыть контрол. А я предотвращаю только его уничтожение, а контрол уже закрылся, поэтому и зависает. Попробую предотвратить WM_CLOSE

Comment: А через JS хук на close() поставить не вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того, чтобы переопределять *WM_DESTROY* (которое вызывается когда уже слишком поздно), нужно переопределить функцию close на уровне JavaScript. Для этого нужно будет добавить ссылку на COM объект Microsoft HTML Object Library и воспользоваться интерфейсом *IHTMLScriptElement* для добавления в каждую загружаемую страницу сценария со своей функцией close. В старых версиях IE это можно сделать присваиванием `window.close = function ()...`, но в IE11 это почему-то не работает, хотя то же самое достигается просто определением своей функции close.

Чтобы форма могла получать уведомления от JavaScript через вызовы *window.external*, нужно будет добавить к ней атрибут *ComVisible* и присвоить ее свойству веб браузера *ObjectForScripting*. Пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsTest1
{
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public void NotifyClose()
        {
            //попытка закрытия WebBrowser...
        } 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
        }        

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // here we override the functionality of window.close
            HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
            mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement element = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
            try
            {
                element.text = "function close() { window.external.NotifyClose();  } ";
                head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(element);
            }
        }  
    }     

}
```

[Источник](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9384257-f83c-4186-a59d-cb991273211d/webbrowser-control-and-windowclosing-event?forum=Offtopic)